# curl send json with variables

Tags: shell, curl, webhooks, microsoft-teams

How could I send a JSON-Object via curl to an Incoming Webhook from Microsoft Teams? The JSON is filled with content from a variable.

```sh
alarmmeldung=`cat file.txt`
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"text": $alarmmeldung}' https://incomingwebhookurl
```

Always I get "Bad payload received by generic incoming webhook" as response.

If I put quotes around the `$alarmmeldung` then the request could be sent but I get the text $alarmmeldung. What I actually want is the content of $alarmmeldung.

How I have to write the curl statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need replace the single quotes with double quotes to get the variable to be interpolated. You also need to add double quotes around the variable so that it valid json.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{\"text\": \"$alarmmeldung\"}" https://incomingwebhookurl
```

If you don't want to do handle the escaping, you can also just included the complete json body as a file:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @file.json https://incomingwebhookurl
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the one that answered by @pafjo and it works fine for me but I need to add some message and also use variable in the same message, in this case use the following curl

```
'$' curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{\"text\": 'Repo \"$REPO_NAME\" already exists'}" https://incomingwebhookurl
```

here repo name is my variable that I pass when ever I trigger github actions using workflow_dispatch